# How to convert 16 bit unsigned int to 8 bit unsigned char & finally return in an unsigned char*?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char

I have a vector of *8 bit* `unsigned char`s & a vector of *16 bit* `unsigned short`s

```
std::vector<unsigned char> eight_bit_array;
std::vector<unsigned short> sixteen_bit_array;

sixteen_bit_array.resize(x_number_of_samples);
eight_bit_array.resize((x_number_of_samples)*2);
```

I have populated some data into the `sixteen_bit_array`. Thats cool. **I want to know if it is possible to typecast & store the `sixteen_bit_array` & into the `eight_bit_array` & How ?**

I have a method which returns the `eight_bit_array` by returning a pointer to `unsigned char` like so:

```
// A legacy method which returns the char array
unsigned char *GetDataSample(std::size_t sample_number) {
    return &eight_bit_array[sample_number];
}
```

So I want to typecast & store the `sixteen_bit_array` into the `eight_bit_array` so that I can return `16 bit unsigned ints` without having to change the return type of my legacy method from `unsigned char *` to `unsigned short *`

*Please suggest how to do this.*

Comment: off: don't start variable name with numbers

Comment: @pergy I corrected this in the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some `memcpy` magic but you need to make sure your types are actually 8 and 16 bits respectively:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    std::vector<uint16_t> uint16vals{11, 1, 0, 3};
    std::vector<uint8_t> uint8vals(uint16vals.size() * 2);
    std::memcpy(&uint8vals[0], &uint16vals[0], sizeof(uint16_t) * uint16vals.size());
}
```

Comment: you are not exactly using `unsigned short`s & `unsigned char`s but close to what I was looking for

Comment: @HAL9000-Kernel I did that on purpose since these types give more guarantees over their size & express intent since you're looking for 8 & 16 bits.

Comment: So, I don't loose any information if I do it this way ?

Comment: @Hal9000-Kernel No, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise operations:

```
std::pair<unsigned char, unsigned char> split(unsigned short n) {
    // set to 0 the bit outside of a 8bit unsigned int
    unsigned char low = n & (1 << 8);
    // get the bit higher than 2^8
    unsigned char high = n >> 8;
    return {high, low};
}
```

(The shift value should be good but TBH I'm not 100% sure)

BTW, use fixed size type and not implementation dependant size type when you make assumption on the size of the type

**EDIT**

to merge two 8 bit integer you can do something like this:

```
unsigned short split(unsigned char h, unsigned char l) {
    return (h << 8) + l;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do reinterpret_cast the whole vector<unsigned short> to vector<unsigned char> ? & thus avoid this complex bit magic ?

Comment: You can use reinterpret_cast to convert a unsigned short to an unsigned char but you will lose the "high" bits. (reinterpret cast to convert unsigned char to unsigned short will give you garbage)

Comment: so, that is a reason I should choose to do the bit magic to compared to a reinterpret_cast ?

Comment: If you don't want to use bitwise operation, you can use @GillBates solution but I do not see a way to use reinterpret_cast without losing (useful) informations.

Comment: thanks @nefas. both the solutions are good to know for anyone looking out with this problem